# How to fully migrate Joomla website to AWS EC2, S3 and CDN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, joomla, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cdn

I am getting confused with hosting my files on AWS. I am migrating my Joomla website to amazon web service. I transferred my files to EC2 instance & also moved the images to S3 bucket, but now I am confused with the S3 & CDN service. I don't know how to implement these.

Kindly tell me the detailed steps/tutorials so that I can implement the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [AWS S3 CDN integration guide](https://www.keycdn.com/support/aws-s3-cdn-integration/) that may help guide you in the right direction. Since you mentioned that you are using Joomla, you can also perform a [Joomla CDN integration](https://www.keycdn.com/support/joomla-cdn-integration/) directly from within your Joomla site.